# Struct aninhada - Dificuldade em entender o conceito

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Tenho as seguintes estruturas:

```
typedef struct DataNode

{

    int id;

} DataNode;


typedef struct Node

{

    DataNode data;
    struct Node *Next;

} Node;

typedef struct List 

{

    int size;
    Node *head;

} List;
```

Fiz um desenho para entender essas estruturas aninhadas pois estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade para entender o conceito de estruturas aninhadas. As estruturas acima é igual ao desenho abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado.

Comment: Parece que você entendeu sim, o desenho está correto. Não vi dúvida aí. A única coisa que pelo menos no código isso não são exatamente estruturas aninhadas. São estruturas compostas por campos com seus tipos, por acaso alguns destes tipos também são estruturas. O aninhamento ocorreria se uma estrutura estivesse dentro da outra de forma direta no código. Porém na organização da memória fica parecido com seu desenho.

Comment: Como dito pelo usuário @Maniero, aparentemente você realmente entendeu o conceito, lhe sugiro que toda a vez que for fazer um Struct desenhe no papel como ela irá se conectar com as demais, parece algo bobo, porém para alguém que esta com duvidas pode ajudar muito e na hora da prova (se for seu caso) diminui a chance de erro, é só uma dica boba mesmo, mas que pode salvar a vida...